# Can Big $O$ ever be negative? How does those concepts relate to the limit definition?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, asymptotics

So for some time I am trying to figure out big $O$ and small $o$ notation and I understand the main idea behind those notations but when I try to dig a bit deeper it seems I can't figure some stuff, anyways my problems are:
In some of my textbook, the limit definition of big O is: $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=b$$ where $a\in \mathbb{R}$ $\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$

I also know there is this definition of big O $|f(x)|\leq C|g(x)| $ where C is some positive constant. So here are my questions

1. In some textbooks it says that the value of the limit definition should be $0<b<\infty$. So can  the value of the limit be any real number or does it has to be strictly positive(i know it can be zero also but they often don't specify it) and why is that?.
2. I guess this question relates to to the first one. In other definition of big $O$, why $C$ has to be positive constant and why $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have to be positive. Why they must be represented in terms of absolute value?

When I am thinking about big O, I often think about it in terms of a graphs. Lets say we have some function $h(x)$ whos limit value approaches lets say $-2$ when x goes for example to infinity. Why can't we say for example that $h(x) = O(-1)$? I understand that this holds by the above definition but I don't understand the bigger picture of why is it like that, which leeds me to  third question

3. When observing big $O$ on graph, do we only look how funtions are bounded by each other from the positive upper part of the graph where $y$ value is positive and if so, why is it like that?
4. I guess the "limit definition" of big $O$ is not a real definition but rather to show there must be some constant ratio of change between those two functions. Am I right about that? If so, is there some example why "limit definition" of big $O$ is not equivalent with the $|f(x)|\leq C |g(x)|$

In a nutshell, I see all my question are related to each other and similar but I tried to categorize it a bit. I hope I was clear about my confusions.

Answer (score 1):

The "limit definition" is just wrong. Take $f(x) = \sin x$ and $g(x) = \sin x + 10$, then $f = O(g)$ as $x \to \infty$, but $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ doesn't exist. And there need not be any "constant ratio" - $f$ can be sometimes significantly smaller than $g$.

Correct definition is as follow: $f(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x \to a$, if there exists constant $C$ s.t. for all $x$ close to $a$, $|f(x)| < C \cdot |g(x)|$. If we say "exists constant $C > 0$" - we get equivalent definition, so some sources can include this requirement, while others can omit.

If some source (usually related to algorithms) is interested only in positive functions, they can introduce this definition only for functions $f$ and $g$ that take non-negative value, and drop absolute value in definition. This is equivalent to original definition for such functions.

When we look at graph, we are interested in both positive and negative values, $f = O(g)$ is equivalent to $|f| = O(g)$ or to $f = O(|g|)$.

And yes, if we have say $h(x) = 2 + x$, and $g(x) = -2$ then we totally can say that $h(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x \to 0$. This is not very common, because usually when we speak about asymptotics - $h = O(g)$ - this is because we want to replace $h$ with something simpler, and in this case it makes sense to choose some $g$ that is easier to work with.

Comment: Hmm, so let me see if I got this right. in that example for $h(x) = 2 + x$ and $g(x) = -2$ and since you said we can say $h(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ then we can use the definition like this: $f(x) \leq  C * g(x)$ where $f$ and $g$ can be also negative and in other way we can also say $2+x \leq C * (-2)$ for some $C  < 0$? Which would imply that we don't need to look only positive values of $f$ and $g$ and $C$?

Comment: No, definition $f(x) \leq C \cdot g(x)$ works only when $f$ and $g$ are non-negative. If you want to work with arbitrary functions, you have to use $|f(x)| \leq C \cdot |g(x)|$ definition - that will give $|2 + x| \leq C \cdot |-2|$, which is true for say $C = 2$ and $|x| \leq 1$.

Comment: Okay I understand it works like that using the definition but my main confusion from the post was, why the definition of big $O$ uses absolute value of a functionss as like what is the reason behind it, why not define big $O$ without absolute values?

Comment: Because I imagine that big O is telling us: there is a function $g$ that is above(bounded above)  function $f$. That is how many teachers present it. At least, that is how they present it when values of $f$ and $g$ are bigger than 0. How can we than look as -2 being above 2+x? Is my concept of looking at big $O$ wrong?

Comment: Because we often care about absolute value of function, and not about sign. Moreover, we often use $O$-notation with normed space, where we can compare only "absolute value" (norm) of elements, not elements themselves. If values of $f$ and $g$ are greater than $0$, then both definitions are equivalent, but generalisation to all functions requires to take absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

There are really two conflicting "definitions" of how Big-O works; the mathematician's version (true version) and the software engineer's version (note *not* computer scientist). Note I put "definition" in quotes as the software engineer version isn't normally defined rigorously.

These two actually are used quite differently in practice which is why I think you are having a point of confusion with the different definitions. I go over the differences [here](https://wjmccann.com/course/computationalcomplexity/sections/practicalbigo/) in some pretty long winded blog posts for my students however the tldr is as follows

- *Software Engineers* use Big-O as a form of an equivalence relation for worst case algorithm growth, as they want a way to compare different algorithms to each other. You mentioned in your post that they grow with a similar ratio. This is why you have $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=b$ with $0<b<\infty$, because if $b=0$ then you wouldn't get an equivalence relation. Algorithm runtimes are positive (you can't have negative time) which is the answer to your question about why not negative.
- *Mathematicians* use Big-O as a way to describe how you can expect things to grow (or decay) over time in the worst case. I think an illuminating example for why you take the absolute value would be to ask what the growth rate of $-x^2$ is. Clearly for every value of $x$, $-x^2<1$ so if we didn't take the absolute value of $-x^2$, then we would say $-x^2\in\mathcal{O}(1)$ which is pretty worthless.

To answer your final question about $\mathcal{O}(-1)$, you could do that if you wanted to, its just not common as its customary to simplify your expression inside the $\mathcal{O}$.

---

As a brief aside, the mathematician and software engineer definitions are not as unrelated as people make them out to be, and with a little work you can link the two together.